# Sencha Touch 2 Tab Panel: Contents in other tabs are in the wrong place

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I'm learning Sencha Touch 2, and I'm confused by a tab panel problem.

This is how I define my view.

```
Ext.define('NewApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
config: {
    activeItem: 1,
    items: 
    [{
        title: 'info',
        iconCls: 'info',
        items: 
        [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'button1',
        }]
    },
    {
        title: 'more',
        iconCls: 'more'
    }]
}
```

});

And in app.js:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'NewApp',

requires: [
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.Button'
],

views: [
    'Main'
],

launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('NewApp.view.Main'));
},
```

});

It's pretty simple. On one tab named 'info' there is a button ,while on the other tab 'more', nothing. The activeItem is set to 1 to make sure that the tab titled 'more' will be shown first.
However, when I launched the app I found the output different from expectation.

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VTym.jpg)

The button, which should be shown on the first tab, now shows on not only the first tab, but also the second tab. However, when I slide to the 'info' tab and slide back to 'more' tab, the button is gone.

Can anyone tell me what should I do to get rid of the button on the second tab at first scene?

Comment: Do you need further help or did one of the answer answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to set the activeItem in the list.

Add to the launch method the following line:

```
Ext.Viewport.down('.tabpanel').setActiveItem(1);
```

That way it works.

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar issues because of 'docked' property.

Try setting the tabbar docker bot or change the layout configs.

ST is not quite friendly with those property when they are not defined correctly.